# java servlet url mapping doesn't work

Tags: java, servlets

In the java servlet, how to do mapping with this url :

```
http://localhost8080/myproject/client/1234
```

the 'myproject' is my root context.

I have tried the `/**/client/*` , it doesn't work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong

First of all URL should be

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/client/1234
```

then for doing mapping do it like

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/client/* </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```